# How to extract data from an already existing database with genexus?

Tags: genexus

I am trying to create a model on genexus that gets data from a determined table from a server to create a File.

I have tried doing it while creating a new knowledge base but I didn't know how I can get the data I need or how I can connect the existing tables to my knowledge base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this 2 links from GeneXus documentation:

- https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?2414,Reverse%20Engineering%20Process
- https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6627,Database+Reverse+Engineering+Wizard,

Best Regards.

Comment: Thank you that's what i need it